# Plotly Dash - Fire Callback only when switch state changes

Tags: callback, state, plotly-dash

I have the following problem in Plotly Dash:
I have a bool-switch, whose state I update every 10 seconds by the interval method to check if it has been changed by a second program that is running in the background.
Structure (simplified)

```
    app.layout(
    html.div(id='switch')
    )

    @app.callback(Input('switch', 'on'),
                  Output("tracing_status","children"))
    def act_when_switch_state_changes():
       do_something()
    return output

    @app.callback(Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
                  Output('switch','children'))
    def check switch_state():
        state = read_datebase()
        return html.div(daq.BooleanSwitch('id'='switch', on = state))
```

The callback for the switch gets fired every time I update it's state in the interval-component. However, I only want it to fire, when its state has changed. Due to the stateless design, I am struggling here.

Do you have a solution for my problem?

Thank you!
So after 10 minutes the callback counter gives me 60 for the interval-component and 59 for the switch - even though I don't change the switch state.

edit:
Alternatively, is there a way to change the switches state via its properties like `switch.on = True` without having to return and reload the entire Div(switch) element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to change switches without recreating the `daq.BooleanSwitch` element everytime, and it's the way you should take. Instead, include the switch in your basic layout and directly address its state. Minimal example:

```
import random
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_daq as daq

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='text-output'),
    daq.BooleanSwitch(id='switch', on=True),
    dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=1000),
])

@app.callback(Output('text-output', 'children'),
                Input('switch', 'on'))
def act_when_switch_state_changes(switch):
    return 'switch is on' if switch else 'switch is off'

@app.callback(Output('switch', 'on'),
                Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
                State('switch', 'on'),
                prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_switch_state(n_intervals, old_state):
    new_state = random.choice([True, False]) # coin flip
    return dash.no_update if new_state == old_state else new_state

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I replaced your `read_database()` by a random coin flip to get the new state, but it could of course be anything that return a bool.

Note how `old_state` is used in `update_switch_state` to make sure the switch's value is only updated when it actually changes. Doing so prevents callbacks with `('switch', 'on')` as `Input` from firing when the switch doesn't change.

Comment: excellent anwser! 
thank you for showing me, how to directly address the state of the switch :)